# sort in Ascending Order

Tags: c#-4.0

Input->windows 7 was released on 1 Jan 2017
Output
1
7
2017
Jan
on
released
was
windows

Comment: And are you asking us to write the code for you now?

Comment: where did you get stuck? this *looks* like a loop with a try-parse and either append or sum...? tip: "here's the code that I think should work, but I'm having {specific problem}; what am I doing wrong?" style questions get *much* better responses than "now you go write the code for me" (which are generally hammered hard into the ground; this isn't code-as-a-service)

Comment: Your (additional) homework for today will be studying `Console.WriteLine(_obj.Aggregate((sum: 0, concat: ""), (t, x) => int.TryParse(x, out var i) ? (t.sum + i, t.concat) : (t.sum, t.concat + x)));`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm sure a beginer would spend less time solving this problem than understanding what `Aggregate` does and finding the name of the type returned in your example ;)

Comment: @Cid: absolutely -- it's *optional* additional homework. :-P Using this as the solution without being able to explain it when questioned is at one's own risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did little example to understand object parsing into int type parameter.

```
List<object> _obj = new List<object>() { "10", "20", "30", "d", "a", "t" };

int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < _obj.Count; i++)
{
    int temp;

    //parsing object into int type, when we cant parse object will be 0
    int.TryParse(_obj[i].ToString(), out temp);

    //sum values
    sum = sum + temp;
}
```

Comment: Here's a `linq` alternative: `_obj.Sum(x => int.TryParse(x, out int myInt) ? myInt : 0);`?

Comment: I am sure to understand basics code need to be more simple without linq.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  sum = sum + temp is the same as sum += temp.  The comment is misleading

Comment: sum=60 is correct  how to concatenate stirng?